# SQL join Case Results with Data from Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case, union

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the results of the Case include the results of the data. My cases are 1 and 2 which go to a table resulting in 2 columns ID | Status | StatusDescription. I'd like to join the results of the data along with the results of the CASE.

I have a Table for the Results and 2 tables that are being joined in the Case.

```
@ZipCode    varchar(5),
@Tribal     varchar(5)

as

DECLARE @Status varchar(30)
SELECT @Status = CASE
when exists (SELECT ZipCodeCoverage.ZipCode, ZipCodeCoverage.State, ServicePlan, plan_name
 FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[ZipCodeCoverage]
    JOIN [VcareData].[dbo].[tbl_plan] ON [ZipCodeCoverage].[State]= [plan_state]

where ZipCode = @ZipCode and is_tribal = @Tribal and life_line = 'Y')   then '1' 
ELSE 2
 END
Select * FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[LifelinePlanStatusCodes]
    where ID = @Status
```

Status code Table

```
ID |   STATUS     | StatusDescription
1  |   Success    | Transaction May Proceed
2  |   FAIL       | Do not continue
```

What I need my Results to be

```
ID |  STATUS | StatusDescription | ZipCode | State |  ServicePlan | plan_name
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you fully understand what a case statement is by the way you present your question here.  A case statement is somewhat like an if...you can use it in a select statement.   Something like : select fields, (your case statement) from table

Comment: That being said can you recommend an alternative solution as to what I might want to try?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. here is what I came up with

```
@ZipCode    varchar(5),
@Tribal     varchar(5)

as

DECLARE @Status varchar(30)

 SELECT @Status = CASE
when exists (SELECT ZipCodeCoverage.ZipCode, ZipCodeCoverage.State, ServicePlan, plan_name
 FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[ZipCodeCoverage]
    JOIN [VcareData].[dbo].[tbl_plan] ON [ZipCodeCoverage].[State]=[plan_state]
       where ZipCode = @ZipCode and is_tribal = @Tribal and life_line = 'Y')  then '1' 
 ELSE 2
 end


 Select *
 ,(SELECT ZipCodeCoverage.ZipCode  
 FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[ZipCodeCoverage]
    JOIN [VcareData].[dbo].[tbl_plan] ON [ZipCodeCoverage].[State]=[plan_state]
       where ZipCode = @ZipCode and is_tribal = @Tribal and life_line = 'Y') as ZipCode
 ,(SELECT ZipCodeCoverage.State 
 FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[ZipCodeCoverage]
    JOIN [VcareData].[dbo].[tbl_plan] ON [ZipCodeCoverage].[State]=[plan_state]
       where ZipCode = @ZipCode and is_tribal = @Tribal and life_line = 'Y') as State
    ,(SELECT ServicePlan 
 FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[ZipCodeCoverage]
    JOIN [VcareData].[dbo].[tbl_plan] ON [ZipCodeCoverage].[State]=[plan_state]
       where ZipCode = @ZipCode and is_tribal = @Tribal and life_line = 'Y') as ServicePlan
  ,(SELECT plan_name
 FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[ZipCodeCoverage]
    JOIN [VcareData].[dbo].[tbl_plan] ON [ZipCodeCoverage].[State]=[plan_state]
       where ZipCode = @ZipCode and is_tribal = @Tribal and life_line = 'Y') as plan_name
FROM [LifelineReference].[dbo].[LifelinePlanStatusCodes]
    where ID = @Status
```

Giving me the Results of:

```
 ID Status  StatusDescription   ZipCode State   ServicePlan plan_name
  1 SUCCESS Service is Available    48322   MI  ABC Michigan Wireless XXXX Service Free250
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab at a cleaner solution that doesn't repeat the same SQL statement and does it in one query. It's a little difficult not fully understanding the fields of the tables involved, their data, and their relationship. I'm assuming ZipCodeCoverage relates zip codes to states, that fields like is_tribal and life_line are part of tbl_plan, and that a status 2 record exists in LifelinePlanStatusCodes.

### Update

The solution below uses a common table expression (CTE) so that the query isn't repeated. However, after better understanding what you're looking for it might just be clearer to use an if exists (...), select the result you want, else select the FAIL record. That repeats part of the query once, but the intent is also clear. Alternatively, I don't know how you're consuming the results but I'd tend to handle the fail condition in the calling app -- only return the success record (using the first query) and if no record was returned treat it as a fail.

In any case, the CTE solution gets your plan in the FoundPlan_CTE and is joined to the status codes, but the status code selected is 1 (success) if FoundPlan_CTE returned any records, or 2 (fail) if FoundPlan_CTE returned no records.

```
with FoundPlan_CTE (ZipCode, State, ServicePlan, plan_name)
as
(
    select
        z.ZipCode
        ,z.State
        ,p.ServicePlan
        ,p.plan_name
    from
        [LifelineReference].[dbo].[ZipCodeCoverage] z
        inner join [VcareData].[dbo].[tbl_plan] p on p.plan_state = z.State
    where
        z.ZipCode = @ZipCode
        and p.is_tribal = @Tribal
        and p.life_line = 'Y'
)
select
    s.ID
    ,s.Status
    ,s.StatusDescription
    ,p.ZipCode
    ,p.State
    ,p.ServicePlan
    ,p.plan_name
from
    [LifelineReference].[dbo].[LifelinePlanStatusCodes] s
    left outer join FoundPlan_CTE p on 1 = 1
where
    s.ID = isnull((select top 1 1 from FoundPlan_CTE),2)
```

Comment: Tried that, much cleaner, however the returned values came back with ALL data rather than a specific row

       ID Status StatusDescription ZipCode State ServicePlan plan_name
     1 SUCCESS Service is Available 48322 MI ARV15 Michigan Wireless Lifeline Service Free250
     2 FAILED NO Service Available in this Area 48322 MI ARV15 MI PAY AS YOU GO
     2 FAILED NO Service Available in this Area 48322 MI ARV15 MI Non Lifeline UNLIMITED TALK & TEXT
     2 FAILED NO Service Available in this Area 48322 MI ARV15 MI Non Lifeline 250 TALK OR 500 TEXT 30 DAYS

Comment: That would be equivalent to only life_line = 'Y' records. I edited my answer to reflect that. Given that, you could also get rid of the case statement and join on s.ID = 1 or s.Status = 'SUCCESS', but I left the case statement to make sure your original meaning was clear; you may wish to change that.

Comment: That resolved the success and looks good but still need the failed to show up on else. No data still shows.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your original intent. Made one last update -- not crazy about it or general approach -- but hopefully that does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result when 1 When 1 only the 1st row should show. When 2 a failed should show with no additional info.. 
When 2 NO data shows up all .. almost as if the result is run after the case...

```
ID  Status  StatusDescription   ZipCode State   ServicePlan plan_name
1   SUCCESS Service is Available    48322   MI  ARV15   Michigan Wireless Lifeline Service Free250
2   FAILED  NO Service Available in this Area   48322   MI  ARV15   MI PAY AS YOU GO
2   FAILED  NO Service Available in this Area   48322   MI  ARV15   MI Non Lifeline UNLIMITED TALK & TEXT
2   FAILED  NO Service Available in this Area   48322   MI  ARV15   MI Non Lifeline 250 TALK OR 500 TEXT 30 DAYS
```